# Is it possible to draw HTML contents in Vaadin 14 flow Label?

Tags: vaadin-flow

Is it possible to draw HTML contents in Vaadin 14 flow `Label`? I know, it is available in Vaadin 7 package like below:

```
Label label = new Label("<br>title", ContentMode.HTML);
```

I have texts with `<br>` contents. Is there any alternative available to let the label to use them in Vaadin 14 flow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible. Example code:

```
Label label = new Label();
label.add(new Html("<b>bold text</b>"));
```

Make sure that you actually need a `Label` instead of `Span` or `Div`. The HTML tag `<label>` is intended as label for input fields, see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp).